# can template function have multiple return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I m a student. I m performing the arithmetic operation(subtraction, addition, multiplication, division) using a template but facing some difficulty:

some arithmetic operation(subtraction,multiplication,division) not run? I want to run all arithmetic operation using template

link of the programme:https://onlinegdb.com/r1RUMCU_8

program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T> 

T arithmaticop(T x, T y) //pass data type as a parameter
{ 
   return x+y;
   return x*y;
   return x/y;
   return x-y;
} 

int main()
{
    cout << arithmaticop<int>(10, 5); 
}
```

o/p

15        //here **only give the only addition**

I refer this link:http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: No, a single function can reach only a single return statement. You have to either define a separate function for each operation (possibly add a template parameter, representing the arithmetic operation, to the existing function) or pack all those results into a vector/array/structure/whatever.

Comment: You've misunderstood what templates are for. Templates allow you to write one function that operates on many different *types*. It doesn't mean that you can write a function that returns multiple values.

Comment: @john I m facing the error ‘T’ does not name a type https://onlinegdb.com/SJMWk1v_8    help

Comment: @rahul_ You need to put `template <class T>` before **all** of your functions, not just the first one.

Comment: @john now run the fine can I add solution in above question

Answer (score 0):

Template are not related to the result you're getting.
Template can be used to handle multiple types not multiple values.

The function exit as soon as a return is encountered, so only the first operation of your function is performed the others are completely ignored, because the code exit with the first operation returns:

```
return x+y
```

if you want your code to perform every operations you've list and just print the result, you can do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <class T> 
std::string arithmaticop(T x, T y) //pass data type as a parameter
{ 
    std::stringstream resultStringStream;
    resultStringStream << x+y;
    resultStringStream << x-y;
    resultStringStream << x*y;
    resultStringStream << x/y;
    return resultStringStream.str();
}
```

Comment: where I can pass the value x(10) and y(5) ?

Comment: you can still call arithmaticop as before int main()
    {
        cout << arithmaticop<int>(10, 5); 
    }